# Implementing incremental client updates with rowversions in Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I am a newcomer to Postgres and love it so far. I've given this problem a lot of thought already, RTFM to the best of my ability, but hit a dead end, so I need a nudge in the right direction.

I'm designing a database where each entity of interest has a `rowversion` column that gets assigned a value from a global sequence. So, in the simplest scenario, in a table `emps` with two rows: `emp1` with `rowversion@3` and `emp2` with `rowversion@5`, I know `emp2` was modified after `emp1` (ie in a later transaction - don't really mind if rows within the same transaction have the same `rowversion`).

This is to form the foundation of a *data sync logic*, where a client that knows they have everything up until @3, can get the latest updates using a query such as `SELECT * FROM emps WHERE rowversion>3 and rowversion<=new_anchor`.

Here is an example scenario for a client already updated @3 - assume the following transactions since:

```
@3 - committed
@4 - committed
@5 - committed
@6 - in progress - not committed yet
@7 - committed
@8 - in progress - not committed yet
@9 - committed
```

Client update is performed in three stages:

1. Ask the database for an appropriate `new_anchor`.
2. Perform `SELECT * FROM emps WHERE rowversion>3 and rowversion<=new_anchor`.
3. Pass the `new_anchor` value back to the client, along with the result data.

Since the rows with `rowversion` @6 and @8 are still in progress, `new_anchor` has to be @5, *so that our range query doesn't miss any uncommitted updates*. Now the client can be confident it has everything up until @5.

So the actual problem distilled: **how can this `new_anchor` be safely determined without forcing `SERIALIZABLE` or otherwise seriously hurting performance?**

As you can probably tell I've borrowed this idea from SQL Server, where this problem is trivially solved by the `min_active_rowversion()` function. This function would return @6 in the above scenario, so your `new_anchor` can safely be `min_active_rowversion() - 1`. I sort of had an idea how this could be implemented in Postgres using an `active_rowversions` table, triggers, and `SELECT min(id) FROM active_rowversions`, but that would require `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation, which is not available in Postgres.

I would really appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the solution is much simpler than initially thought, thanks to Postgres' [System Information Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-info.html).

- `txid_current()` can be used in a trigger to assign a record's `rowversion`.
- `txid_snapshot_min(txid_current_snapshot())` can be used to get the minimum active transaction in the same way an SQL Server user might use `min_active_rowversion()`.

The best part is these are 64-bit, permanent, non-subject to vacuuming:

> These functions export a 64-bit format that is extended with an "epoch" counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation.

Postgres is truly amazing.